# Global Planner Parameters in Navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, planner, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was wondering what the parameters below are exactly doing in the global planner ([Reference Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navfn)). The description is not very clear to me. I tried different values for the parameters in my yaml file, but it didn't seem to be affecting the global planner:

```
   ~<name>/planner_window_x (double, default: 0.0)
                 
         Specifies the x size of an optional window to restrict the planner to. This can be useful for restricting NavFn to work in a small window of a large costmap.

   ~<name>/planner_window_y (double, default: 0.0)
                
      Specifies the y size of an optional window to restrict the planner to. This can be useful for restricting NavFn to work in a small window of a large costmap.
```

and I was wondering if they are visualizable in RViz?

Here is my yaml file

```
NavfnROS:
   allow_unknown: false
   planner_window_x: 0.0
   planner_window_y: 0.0
   default_tolerance: 0.05
   visualize_potential: true # false
   planner_costmap_publish_frequency: 0.2
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193764/global-planner-parameters-in-navigation/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am afraid those parameters are unused. If you download the source code of the [navigation stack](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation) and do *grep -R planner_window ** you will get this:

```
global_planner/src/planner_core.cpp:        private_nh.param("planner_window_x", planner_window_x_, 0.0);
global_planner/src/planner_core.cpp:        private_nh.param("planner_window_y", planner_window_y_, 0.0);
global_planner/include/global_planner/planner_core.h:        double planner_window_x_, planner_window_y_, default_tolerance_;
navfn/src/navfn_ros.cpp:      private_nh.param("planner_window_x", planner_window_x_, 0.0);
navfn/src/navfn_ros.cpp:      private_nh.param("planner_window_y", planner_window_y_, 0.0);
navfn/include/navfn/navfn_ros.h:      double planner_window_x_, planner_window_y_, default_tolerance_;
```

Which makes me think that they are declared and initialised, but never used. Maybe it is just part of the API and the current global planner implementation does not use it, or may be it is just legacy code that will be removed at some point.

Might be a good idea to open an issue on [github](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2014-09-30**:
am I wrong or actually those commands are just specifying the default parameters in case none are given?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-09-30**:
Yeah, that looks to be the case. Please open up an issue. Was this a behavior you were looking to get, or just curious what the parameters did?

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-30**:
Thanks All. The parameters looked like to be performing a special case of the feature I am trying to implement ([Explained Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/188864/virtual-corridor-for-robot-navigation-updating-costmap/)). So yes I was looking to see how they behave.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-09-30**:
@Procópio Silveira Stein, yes, those commands are just specifying the default parameters in case none are given, but after that they are not used anywhere else in the code.